# Bash script arguments for python are not updating

Tags: python, bash

I am using and a do while loop in bash script and executing a python file with some arguments inside the loop, evetime I loop the arguments are updated and the python file is executed again.

The problem is the changes to the arguments are updated in python file.

Please have a look at my code and correct me... Thanks in advance.

mouse.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

DEVICE="192.168.0.100:5555"

while [ 0 ]
do
    adb -s $DEVICE pull /sdcard/motion.log 2>/dev/null
    adb -s $DEVICE shell  "rm /sdcard/motion.log 2>/dev/null" 2>/dev/null

    cat motion.log 2>/dev/null| while read line

    do
        x=`echo ${line}| cut -d ' ' -f 1`
        y=`echo ${line}| cut -d ' ' -f 2`
        ipython clicker.py ${x} ${y}

    done

        rm motion.log 2>/dev/null

done
```

clicker.py

```
import sys

while True:
    try:
        print (sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    except:
        print ("some error")
```

motion.log

```
27 -1 -121
26 -1 -122
25 0 -122
24 0 -123
23 0 -124
22 0 -125
22 0 -126
21 0 -127
20 1 -128
19 1 -129
18 1 -130
17 2 -131
16 2 -132
15 2 -132
14 3 -134
13 3 -135
12 4 -136
11 4 -138
10 5 -139
9 5 -140
9 6 -141
8 6 -142
7 7 -144
7 8 -146
8 9 -148
9 9 -148
11 10 -150
13 10 -151
15 10 -151
16 11 -152
17 11 -152
19 11 -152
20 12 -151
21 12 -151
22 12 -150
23 13 -149
23 14 -148
23 15 -147
23 15 -146
24 16 -146
24 16 -145
24 17 -144
24 18 -144
24 18 -143
24 19 -142
24 20 -141
24 20 -140
24 21 -139
24 22 -139
24 22 -138
24 23 -137
24 23 -136
24 24 -136
24 24 -135
24 25 -134
23 26 -134
23 26 -133
23 26 -132
23 27 -131
23 28 -131
22 28 -130
22 28 -129
22 29 -128
22 29 -127
21 29 -127
21 30 -126
21 30 -125
20 30 -124
20 31 -123
19 31 -122
19 31 -121
19 32 -120
18 32 -120
18 32 -119
18 32 -118
17 33 -117
16 33 -116
16 33 -115
15 33 -114
15 34 -114
14 34 -113
14 34 -112
13 34 -111
13 34 -110
12 34 -110
12 34 -109
11 35 -108
10 35 -107
10 35 -106
9 35 -105
9 35 -104
8 35 -104
8 35 -103
7 35 -102
7 35 -101
6 35 -100
6 35 -99
5 35 -98
5 35 -97
4 35 -96
3 35 -95
3 35 -94
2 35 -93
1 35 -92
1 35 -91
0 35 -90
0 35 -89
-1 35 -88
-1 35 -87
-2 35 -85
-3 35 -84
-3 35 -83
-4 35 -82
-5 34 -81
-6 34 -80
-6 34 -79
-7 34 -78
-8 34 -77
-8 33 -76
-9 33 -75
-10 33 -74
-10 32 -73
-11 32 -72
-11 32 -71
-12 31 -70
-12 31 -69
-13 31 -68
-13 30 -67
-14 30 -67
-14 30 -66
-15 29 -65
-15 28 -64
-16 28 -63
-16 27 -62
-16 27 -61
-17 26 -60
-17 26 -59
-18 25 -59
-18 25 -58
-18 24 -57
-19 24 -56
-19 23 -56
-19 23 -55
-19 22 -54
-20 22 -54
-20 22 -53
-20 21 -53
-20 21 -52
-20 20 -52
-20 19 -51
-20 18 -51
-20 18 -50
-20 17 -50
-20 16 -50
-20 16 -49
-20 15 -49
-20 14 -49
-20 14 -48
-20 13 -48
-20 12 -48
-20 11 -47
-20 10 -47
-20 9 -47
-20 8 -47
-20 8 -46
-20 7 -46
-20 6 -46
-19 6 -46
-19 5 -46
-19 4 -46
-19 3 -46
-18 3 -46
-18 2 -46
-18 1 -46
-18 0 -46
-17 0 -46
-16 -2 -46
-16 -4 -46
-15 -4 -46
-14 -6 -46
-14 -8 -47
-13 -8 -47
-12 -10 -47
-12 -11 -48
-11 -12 -48
-11 -14 -49
-10 -15 -50
-10 -16 -51
-10 -17 -52
-9 -18 -53
-9 -19 -54
-9 -20 -55
-9 -20 -56
-9 -22 -58
-10 -23 -60
-10 -23 -62
-10 -24 -63
-11 -24 -63
-11 -24 -64
-11 -24 -66
-12 -24 -68
-13 -24 -70
-13 -23 -71
-13 -23 -72
-14 -23 -74
-14 -22 -75
-15 -22 -76
-15 -22 -78
-15 -21 -79
-16 -21 -80
-16 -20 -81
-16 -20 -82
-17 -20 -82
-17 -19 -83
-17 -19 -84
-17 -18 -85
-18 -18 -86
-18 -17 -87
-18 -17 -88
-18 -16 -88
-19 -16 -89
-19 -15 -89
-19 -15 -90
-19 -14 -91
-18 -14 -90
```

Output:

```
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
25 0
```

if the initial value is 25 0 it always outputs 25 0, if the initial value is 100 50 it always outputs 100 50. It is always showing bash script initial value its is not updating.

Comment: Why are you using `ipython` instead of just `python`?

Answer (score 3):

First let's sort out the shell script, it uses some unnecessary external programs.  I will only look at the `for` loop, the rest seems irrelevant to your problem:

```
while read x y unused
do
    python clicker.py $x $y
done < motion.log
```

No need for `cat` and those calls to the `cut` program.

Your python has an infinite loop in it.  The command-line arguments will never change, so your python can be:

```
import sys

try:
    print(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
except:
    print("some error")
```

However, we are *still* very inefficient, calling `python` once for each line.  It would be far better if we did the whole lot in `python` and just passed the filename:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("some error with parameters", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

filename = sys.argv[1]

with open(filename) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        x, y = line.split()[:2]
        print(x, y)
```

Then in `bash` we replace the `for` loop with:

```
python clicker.py motion.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing an infinity loop in your python script it will print only the first arguments on the first time you call the script. Change your python to:

```
import sys

try:
    print (sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
except:
    print ("some error")
```

Comment: `[TerminalIPythonApp] CRITICAL | Bad config encountered during initialization:
[TerminalIPythonApp] CRITICAL | Unrecognized flag: '-28'` now i am getting this error.